Write a dataframe in txt on left margin
I want to create a dataframe like this:
df_finale = pd.DataFrame({'col0': '#define ', 'col1': var, 'col2': ' ', 'col3': var1})

where var is a dataframe of string and var1 is a dataframe made with numbers
and then write it into a txt using python.
with open('C:\python\tests.txt', 'a') as f:
    df_string = df_finale.to_string(header=False, index=False)
    f.write(df_string)

but I see that in the txt the indentation is wrong. I'd like to have all the lines that begins on the left margin

can you give an example of the expected output?

...or at least an example of var and var1?

Not knowing what your data looks like, the best I can suggest is adding the justify= parameter in df.to_string(). It should allow you to decide how you want the items in your .txt file to be aligned relative to their columns. There are more parameters that you can play around with listed here.

in the end I've found this solution
df=tabulate(df, showindex=False, headers=df.columns)

it worked for me, removing the index and maintaining a correct indentation on the left.
This solution was proposed here:
How to set the pandas dataframe data left/right alignment?
